# getEditors() not returning Email address

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-sheets

I am creating an web app on spreadsheet, where I wanted to add user Email ID who edited the document.
Using getEditors() is getting Email address to logger, but when I write to spreadsheet value is coming like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@5e8cd61d`

How to convert that to valid Email address:

Code:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sax63nsnfCDxOKvHta-4sNLh7DqAzwreg1BkhGrZh6E/edit#gid=0")
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editor = ss.getEditors();`

Comment: Why are using getEditors() if you want to write email addresses to cells?

Comment: Provide your full code.

Comment: function doGet(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sax63nsnfCDxOKvHta-4sNLh7DqAzwreg1BkhGrZh6E/edit#gid=0")
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //var editor = ss.getEditors();
 
 
  var now = new Date();
  //ss.getRange('A1').setValue(now);
  sheet.appendRow([now,'Sugar']);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Thanks for ordering !!</b>');
  
}